# How to get auto-width to the absolute position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm not sure if there's another method to get this layout without using absolute positioning.

The width of the `titleAdd__text` class is fixed to `4rem` but I want that to change according to the content and not be fixed. How do I go about it?

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.titleBody {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.titleAdd {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  min-height: 4rem;
  position: relative;
}

.titleAdd__plus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.titleAdd__plus:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.titleAdd__text {
  min-width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0%);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0%);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0%);
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  background-color: #2dc8ff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.titleAdd__body {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 4rem;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="titleBody">
  <div class="titleAdd">
    <div class="titleAdd__plus">
      <div class="titleAdd__text">Add</div>
      <div class="titleAdd__body">Overview the processes of the company functioning</div>
    </div>
    <div class="titleAdd__plus">
      <div class="titleAdd__text">Add</div>
      <div class="titleAdd__body">Implemented multiple predictive models and clustering to cross-sell high profit LAP (loan against property) to current clients. Implemented multiple predictive models and clustering to cross-sell high profit LAP (loan against property) to current
        clients. Implemented multiple predictive models and clustering to cross-sell high profit LAP to current clients. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="titleAdd__plus">
      <div class="titleAdd__text">Add</div>
      <div class="titleAdd__body">Enterprise grade machine learning platform for auto-updating. Enterprise grade machine learning platform for auto-updating. Enterprise grade machine learning platform for auto-updating. </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do `titleAdd__text` as absolute with `top:0` and `bottom:0` - this will provide you that blue div will have same height as parent with position relative (add position relative to `titleAdd__plus`). Then you have to rotate span with text `Add` inside, not whole div and remove `transform-origin`

http://jsfiddle.net/b5vx7q63/2/

> Looks great. Thank You. There's a final minor issue: the text-align: center in titleAdd__text isn't working anymore. Any idea how to go about that?

I found that there is `writing-mode`. I changed some styles of span with `Add` text

http://jsfiddle.net/qztq1osu/2/

Comment: Looks great. Thank You. There's a final minor issue: the `text-align: center` in `titleAdd__text` isn't working anymore. Any idea how to go about that?

Comment: I've seen this only in chrome and that works fine. I will try to fix this in firefox

Comment: I tested on latest version of Chrome, Safari and Firefox. They will seem to be having this issue. Thank you. Looking forward. I'm also trying to get it fixed.

Comment: I found solution - it's in second link to jsfiddle

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so very much :)